# Lie derivative and injectivity

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, 3d, lie-derivative

Let $(M,g)$ be a three-dimensional non-compact Riemannian manifold without boundary (oriented and connected).

> Does there exist a (smooth, global) vector field $X\in\mathfrak{X}(\Sigma)$ such that the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_{X}$ viewed as a map $\mathcal{L}_{X}:C_{c}^{\infty}(\Sigma)\to C^{\infty}_{c}(\Sigma)$ is injective? (The compact support here is crucial in my question).

If the above is not true in general, can we maybe at least formulate some geometrical or topological (e.g. homological) conditions on $(M,g)$ such that it is true, i.e. such that there exists such a vector field?

Comment: Just so you know, there has been major changes in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your question is independent of the metric $g$.

Here is a partial answer (correcting the previous answer). Suppose $M$ admits a vector field so that for a dense set of points $D\subset M$ the closure of the flow $\overline{\{\Phi^t(x)\mid t\in\Bbb R\}}$ is not compact for all $x\in D$ (and the flow is taken for all times at which it is defined). Then $X:C^\infty_c(M)\to C^\infty_c(M)$ is injective.

To see it let $g\in C_c^\infty(M)$ with $X(g)=0$. Then for all points $x\in M$ you have that $\frac{d}{dt}g(\Phi^t(x))=X(g)(\Phi^t(x))=0$ and $g$ is constant along the flow of $X$. In particular if $x\in D$ and $g(x)\neq0$ then $g(y)\neq0$ for all $y$ in some closed but not compact set. This implies that $g$ cannot have compact support, so if $g$ has compact support then $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in D$, which was dense.

Comment: A suitable application of the flow-box Theorem leads to a similar but shorter proof

Comment: Yes, thats a lot simpler.

Comment: After a second thought: if $f$ is compactly supported in $\Bbb R^2$, the map $g(x,y,z) = f(x,y)$ is not compactly supported in $\Bbb R^3$, since its support is $supp(f)\times \Bbb R$.
But I assume that's what you were implicitly using when saying "compactly supported function that does not depend on $x_3$". Am I wrong?

Comment: You are perfectly correct, that was a brain fart. In fact if $g$ is compactly supported, and $X=\partial_{x_3}$, then $g(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_3} X(g)(x_1, x_2,t) dt$ and this shows that $X(g)\neq0$ for any non-zero compactly supported $g$. Something close to the opposite of this answer should then be true.

Comment: Well, that surely deserves an edit then!

Comment: @Didier I've corrected the answer with a partial answer to the converse. I don't know if such a VF with non-proper flow on a dense set exists for all manifolds, but there may also be some other way to build an appropriate vector field.

Comment: Very nice$\,\,$